# Date and time format

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, if-this-then-that, google-sheets-dates

I have lots of dates in the first column in the format output by [`IFTTT`](http://ift.tt):

```
August 23, 2010 at 11:01PM
```

Is there a way to get them formatted in a way that I can then use for date and time calculations?

<sub>Ideally the function will only take up an extra column.</sub>

Comment: I don't believe there is a built in function that will format the date in the way that you want it to. 
`Google Drive` has a built-in `Script Editor` (`Tools` - `Script Editor`) you can use to write a custom script to do what you want. You could post a question on `StackOverflow` if you get stuck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use this formula to convert the date time values IFTTT spits out to a useful format:

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, " at ", " "))
```

<sup>Where A1 is the cell containing the date string</sup>

This gives you a decimal number that you can format as "Date Time".

Comment: The `TIMEVALUE` formula only exists in the new Google Sheets.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra do you know if that is also the case for `DATEVALUE` ?

Comment: @jamesmstone the `DATEVALUE` formula exists in both versions.

Answer (score 2):

The following custom function will transform the string date notation into a date notation:

### Code

```
function myDate(range) {
  var output = [];  
  for(var i=0, iLen=range.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    var rSplit = range[i][0].split(" "), corr = 0;
    if(rSplit[4].substring(5,7) == "PM") {
      corr = 10;
    }   
    var month = parseInt(new Date(Date.parse(rSplit[0]+"1,2013")).getMonth());
    var day = parseInt(rSplit[1].replace(/,/g, ""));
    var year = parseInt(rSplit[2]);
    var hour = parseInt(rSplit[4].substring(0,2))+corr;
    var min = parseInt(rSplit[4].substring(3,5),10);    
    var nDate = new Date(year, month, day, hour, min);
    output.push([nDate]);
  } 
  return output;
}
```

### Remark

Correction is made to account for `AM/PM`. No correction for `GMT`. Add this script via the `Tools` menu in the spreadsheet and select `Script editor`. Save the script and you are ready to go !!

### Usage

`myDate(A1:A4)`

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[string date to date](https://docs.google.com/a/jacobjantuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AluAYY6ZHeWYdDQ3RXdmc3E4ZHBnOUlqYUdSLXdEM0E&usp=sharing)**

Comment: I believe `corr` should equal `12`however as the edit would be less then 6 characters i cant change it

Comment: After testing the code. I noticed for the time `11:09PM` (_regardless of the year_) it always returns `1/1/1970 11:00:00`.

So for example `August 23, 2010 at 11:09PM` returns `1/1/1970 11:00:00`

do you have any idea why?

Comment: I have updated @Jacob 's example [sheet](https://docs.google.com/a/jacobjantuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AluAYY6ZHeWYdDQ3RXdmc3E4ZHBnOUlqYUdSLXdEM0E&usp=sharing) to reflect this

Comment: @jamesmstone see revised code, it works for the example in the spreadsheet.I had to force the `parseInt(text, 10)` to decimals. The `corr` is set at `corr=10` because this will yield the same time. I did not take into account the different time zones.

Comment: Thanks. Quick question is the function `parseInt()` the same as the javascript `parseInt()` . do google macros use javascript?

Answer (score -3):

You can also use one of the display format scripts, this keeps the underlying numbers the same as normal display formats and as such won't corrupt any date/time numerical calculations.

so a script search for 'Format' and get one of the number and date ones, the format to be used is the same as the =Text(,"") variation without needing to be in sheet converted.

MMMM d, yyyy at h:mma

For:

August 23, 2010 at 11:01PM

For other formatting options see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Why would one visit Microsoft Developer Network for formats in Google Spreadsheets?